# Drush sql-sync failing with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: database, drush

I'm having no luck with sql-sync, there's two seemingly unrelated errors it's throwing at me which I'll detail below.

I've been successfully sql-sync'ing the same site to another server, so I'm pretty sure it's the remote server, not the local server, that is causing the problems. The remote server MySQL version is: 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

1) Adding the `--create-db` switch gives me:

`ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'database'`

2) Regardless of whether or not I use the `--create-db` switch, I always get this:

```
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '��T'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the output of the command using the `-v` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I'd installed Drush 6 on the remote server, while my local version was Drush 7. Upgrading solved the problem.